# explode multiple delimiters in php

Tags: php, arrays, explode

My array looks like:

```
{flower},{animals},{food},{people},{trees}
```

I want to explode with `{`, `,` & `}`.

My output should contain only words inside curly brackets.

My code:

```php
$array = explode("},{", $list);
```

After execution of this code $array will be

```php
$array = Array ( 
    [0] => {flower 
    [1] => animals 
    [2] => food
    [3] => people 
    [4] => trees} 
)
```

But output array should be:

```php
$array = Array ( 
    [0] => flower 
    [1] => animals 
    [2] => food
    [3] => people 
    [4] => trees 
)
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I modify my code to get this array?

Comment: Regex match is a better idea

Comment: You can just cut the outer curly braces off with `trim` first, `explode("},{", trim($list, '{}'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for preg_split like below

```
<?php

$list = "{flower},{animals},{food},{people},{trees}";
$array = preg_split('/[},{]/', $list, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($array);
?>
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => flower
    [1] => animals
    [2] => food
    [3] => people
    [4] => trees
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to extract the words using a RegEx instead of splitting the string:

```php
$list = "{flower},{animals},{food},{people},{trees}";

// Match anything between curly brackets
// The "U" flag prevents the regex to make a single match with the first and last brackets
preg_match_all('~{(.+)}~U', $list, $result);

// Only keep the 1st capturing group
$words = $result[1];
var_dump($words);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "flower"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "animals"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "food"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "people"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "trees"
}
```